# Where Can I Download the Summer 18 version of the Salesforce Migration Tool?

Tags: migration, salesforce

I am trying to download the latest version of the force.com migration tool (sometimes called the ANT migration tool.)

The [download page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_install.htm) seems to link to the Summer 2016 version of the tool (see errors below), despite claiming to link to the Summer 2018 version.

When I configure `package.xml` and run the `.jar` like so:

`ant retrieveUnpackaged -lib path/to/ant-salesforce.jar`

I get errors like this:

`[sf:retrieve] package.xml - API version Summer '16 does not have access to Lightning Pages of type CommObjectPage`

Note that this error message is not referring to the API version in the retrieve source sandbox. The sandbox API version is Winter '19.

I've been looking for a while now and still haven't found an alternative download link that correctly points at the Summer 2018 migration tool. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it sounds like the error message is complaining about the version number indicated in the retrieve package manifest, rather than the version of the migration tool.

If you go in the file named `package.xml`, there should be a tag `<version>37.0</version>`. If you change the number to anything 38.0 or higher, I would think the retrieve call should work for you.

Comment: you'd think so, wouldn't you? But I've checked the API versions of the sandboxes involved. Both Winter '19. Thanks for the feedback-- question  updated.